# heightForRowAtIndexPath behaves differently in simulator and device

Tags: ios, objective-c

`heightForRowAtIndexPath` work in simulator but not working in Iphone Device

```
-(CGFloat)tableView: (UITableView*)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath*) indexPath
{
    return Y_Pos;
}
```

Y_Pos is `CGFloat` type variable & I calculate height in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method and store in Y_Pos

The table should calculate a height for the cells, and it does correctly in my simulator, but in a real device it calculates only ones the app is loaded and never recalculates it again. Therefore I have my posts displayed with not right height. What could be the problem?

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work in iPhone device? Can you also provide your cellForRowAtIndexPath implementation?

Comment: The table should calculate a height for the cells, and it does correctly in my simulator, but in a real device it calculates only ones the app is loaded and never recalculates it again. Therefore I have my posts displayed with not right height. What could be the problem?

Comment: I have 4 label  in cell i calculate height like => Y_Pos = cell.name.frame.size.height + cell.address.frame.size.height +cell.details.frame.size.height + cell.mobileno.frame.size.height ;

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using the `estimatedCellHeight`, the Table will call `heightForRowAtIndexPath` for ALL your cells at the beginning. And will never call again unless you do a `reloadData` or `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths...`

If you are using `estimatedCellHeight`, the Table will call `heightForRowAtIndexPath` only for the visible cells and for each new cell when you scroll and the cell appears on screen.

In any case, the Height is cached for all the cells until you reload either the cell or the whole UITableView.

Not sure this is your problem, your question is hard to understand, hope it helps.

Comment: First Two cell height display as per require height but after 3rd cell content overlap on 4th cell ..... , in device . but simulator display correctly